# SOLVED! Rails 7 cant deploy with Capistrano after install esbuild

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-7, esbuild

I have used import map and sprockets in my Rails app for the asset pipeline. I have now installed cssbundling (bootstrap) and jsbundling (esbuild). I then wanted to deploy my project to prod now the deploy crashes at deploy:assets_precompile and asks for a manifest.js. But this is no longer available in esbuild.

What exactly do I have to adjust so that I can use capistrano again and how are the css and js files now compiled for prod?

Do I also need to change something in the nginx config? So that the assets can be loaded?

My files:

Capfile

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"

require "capistrano/rails"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rvm"
require 'capistrano/puma'
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Systemd

install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#
# require "capistrano/rvm"
# require "capistrano/rbenv"
# require "capistrano/chruby"
# require "capistrano/bundler"
# require "capistrano/rails/assets"
# require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
# require "capistrano/passenger"

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

config enviroments production.rb

```
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV["RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES"].present?

  # Compress CSS using a preprocessor.
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Accel-Redirect" # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain.
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  config.action_cable.url = 'wss://smarthome.this-co.de/cable'
  #config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ["http://smarthome.this-co.de", "https://smarthome.this-co.de"]
  Rails.application.config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true

  
  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Include generic and useful information about system operation, but avoid logging too much
  # information to avoid inadvertent exposure of personally identifiable information (PII).
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment).
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "smarthome_production"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Don't log any deprecations.
  config.active_support.report_deprecations = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.assets.digest = true

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require "syslog/logger"
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new "app-name")

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

config deploy.rb

```
lock "~> 3.17.0"

# replace obvious parts
server '89.58.12.188', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true
set :application, "smarthome"
set :repo_url, "++++"
append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml', '.env'

set :user, 'rails'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    2

set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(/home/spinto/.ssh/public) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

append :linked_files, "config/master.key"
append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "public/uploads"
after 'deploy:starting', 'sidekiq:quiet'
after 'deploy:updated', 'sidekiq:stop'
after 'deploy:finished', 'sidekiq:restart'
```

config initializer assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.asset.path.concat [
    Rails.root.join('node_modules', '@fontawesome', 'fontawesome-free')
]
```

config application.rb

```
require_relative "boot"
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load('.env')
require "rails/all"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Smarthome
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 7.0
    config.time_zone = 'Berlin'
    
    config.generators do |g|
      g.template_engine :slim
    end

    

    # Configuration for the application, engines, and railties goes here.
    #
    # These settings can be overridden in specific environments using the files
    # in config/environments, which are processed later.
    #
    # config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
    # config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join("extras")
  end
end
```

i have already adjusted the deploy.rb and the capfile but it didn't help i thought you had to teach cap how to build the new assets.

**Solution:**

i forgot to install the gem 'propshaft' and i had the gem 'bootstrap' installed which sprocket had installed. Sprocket needs the manifest.js and that led to the error.

Comment: *manifest.js. But this is no longer available in esbuild.* - where did you get that idea? you still need that file, it is used by sprockets, esbuild is unrelated to that.

Comment: Yes you are right. i was so stupid and still had the gem bootstrap installed and also i needed gem 'propshaft' to do the precompiling of the assets on deploy